# python move circle around another circle in graphics.py

Tags: python, graphics

I am writing a program in Python using graphics.py library. I want to draw two circles, and then in loop move one of them around another one. I know I have to use sin and cos function, but I have no idea what is a mathematical formula for that.

That's my code:

```
from graphics import *
from math import sin, cos, pi
from time import sleep

win = GraphWin('Program', 500, 500)
win.setBackground('white')

c = Circle(Point(250, 250), 50)
c.draw(win)

c1 = Circle(Point(250, 175), 25)
c1.draw(win)

while True:
    c1.move() #there I have to use some formula for moving circle c1 around circle c
    sleep(1)

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of mathematics have to be used. Based on your example, you want the circles to be adjacent to each other.

Because of that, distance between their centres will always be `r1`+`r2`. This is a length of our vector. We need to split that vector into x axis and y axis parts. This is where sine and cosine functions come in, value it of it at a given angle will mean how far along that axis we have to move our center.

After calculating new position all we have to do is subtract that from current position to see how far we need to move our other circle.

```
from graphics import *
from math import sin, cos, pi
from time import sleep

win = GraphWin('Program', 500, 500)
win.setBackground('white')

c_origin_x = 250
c_origin_y = 250
c_radius = 50

c = Circle(Point(c_origin_x, c_origin_y), c_radius)
c.draw(win)

c1_oldpos_x = c_origin_x # doesn't actually matter, it gets moved immediately
c1_oldpos_y = c_origin_y
c1_radius = 25

c1 = Circle(Point(c1_oldpos_x, c1_oldpos_y), c1_radius)
c1.draw(win)

angle = 0 # initial angle

while True:
    c1_newpos_x = sin(angle) * (c_radius + c1_radius) + c_origin_x
    c1_newpos_y = cos(angle) * (c_radius + c1_radius) + c_origin_y
    c1.move(c1_newpos_x - c1_oldpos_x, c1_newpos_y - c1_oldpos_y)
    sleep(1)
    angle += 0.1 * pi # this is what will make a position different in each iteration
    c1_oldpos_x = c1_newpos_x
    c1_oldpos_y = c1_newpos_y
    
win.getMouse()
win.close()
```